# Showing a Spring transaction in log

Tags: java, spring, transactional

I configured spring with transactional support. Is there any way to log transactions just to ensure I set up everything correctly? Showing in the log is a good way to see what is happening.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

in your `log4j.properties` (for alternative loggers, or log4j's xml format, check the docs)

Depending on your transaction manager, you can set the logging level of the spring framework so that it gives you more info about transactions. For example, in case of using `JpaTransactionManager`, you set

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=INFO
```

(this is the package of the your transaction manager), and also

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=INFO
```

If `INFO` isn't enough, use `DEBUG`

Comment: `INFO` level won't show any tx activity at all, it would be too verbose. `DEBUG` will be necessary there.

Comment: @Bozho I've JpaTransactionManager and I wanna monitor when a connection is borrowed from pool and when it was release for a specific transaction.

Comment: then you'd need to change the logging configuration for your connection pool

Comment: what if we use mybatis+slf4j+logback+springboot?

Answer (score 88):

For me, a good logging config to add was:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor = trace
```

It will show me log like that:

> 2012-08-22 18:50:00,031 TRACE - Getting transaction for [com.MyClass.myMethod]
>
> [my own log statements from method com.MyClass.myMethod]
>
> 2012-08-22 18:50:00,142 TRACE - Completing transaction for [com.MyClass.myMethod]

Comment: Great! No need to have all the info/debug/trace logging of other packages, when this is what you're looking for :D

Comment: I believe this is not working anymore, and this is not the recommended way. See this github issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32393

Answer (score 88):

For Spring Boot application with `application.properties`

```
logging.level.ROOT=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

or if you prefer Yaml (`application.yaml`)

```
logging:
   level:
      org.springframework.orm.jpa: DEBUG
      org.springframework.transaction: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 10):

You could enable JDBC logging as well:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 9):

Most interesting log informations of [`JtaTransactionManager.java`](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.transaction/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.java?r=HEAD) (if this question is still about the `JtaTransactionManager`) are logged at `DEBUG` priority. Assuming you have a `log4j.properties` somewhere on the classpath, I'd thus suggest to use:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you can access Spring classes at runtime, you can determine transaction status.

Comment: Very broken, but try: [Tips for Debugging Spring's @Transactional Annotation](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2012/04/19/tips-for-debugging-springs-transactional-annotation/) (haven't tried it myself yet). It uses [TransactionSynchronizationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) to get transaction status. The code should probably use a thread-local variable to cache the reference to the `isActualTransactionActive()` instead of retrieving it on each logging call.

Answer (score 6):

Here is some code I use in my Logback Layout implementation derived from [ch.qos.logback.core.LayoutBase](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/LayoutBase.html).

I create a thread-local variable to store the reference to the method `org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`. Whenever a new log line is printed out, `getSpringTransactionInfo()` is called and it returns a one-character string that will go into the log.

References:

- [Tips for Debugging Spring's @Transactional Annotation](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2012/04/19/tips-for-debugging-springs-transactional-annotation/)
- [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html)
- [java.lang.ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)
- [java.lang.Class.getMethod()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...))

Code:

```
private static ThreadLocal<Method> txCheckMethod;

private static String getSpringTransactionInfo() {
    if (txCheckMethod == null) {
        txCheckMethod = new ThreadLocal<Method>() {
            @Override public Method initialValue() {           
                try {
                    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                    Class<?> tsmClass = contextClassLoader.loadClass("org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager");
                    return tsmClass.getMethod("isActualTransactionActive", (Class<?>[])null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }                      
            }
         };    
    }
    assert txCheckMethod != null;
    Method m = txCheckMethod.get();
    String res;
    if (m == null) {
        res = " "; // there is no Spring here
    }
    else {
        Boolean isActive = null;
        try {
            isActive = (Boolean) m.invoke((Object)null);
            if (isActive) {
                res = "T"; // transaction active                    
            }
            else {
                res = "~"; // transaction inactive
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exe) {
            // suppress 
            res = "?";
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```