# How do I get transaction info in Spring whether transaction is committed or rollback in a declarative transaction management?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I use following declarative Spring transaction:

```
<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />  
<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Here is the DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )
@Scope("prototype")
public class Xdao{

    public Object getValues(){
        .....
    }
}


@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class Xservice{
private Xdao xdao;

    public Object getx(){
        xdao.getValues();//here I want to know whether the transaction started  is             
        //committed or rollback by aop. Is it possible somehow? I don't want to include that code 
        //in any service or dao layer. 
        .........
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setXdao(Xdao xdao){
        this.xdao=xdao;
    }
}
```

I want to know about transaction status i.e transaction is committed or rolled back. I need it for logging.

Comment: This answer could be handy: [Showing a Spring Transaction in log][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965454/showing-a-spring-transaction-in-log

Answer (score 34):

If transaction is in scope you can get `TransactionStatus` from `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()`. For example:

```
if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
   TransactionStatus status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
   ...
}
```

But this will not work after transaction is completed.

You could add a `TransactionSynchronization` and implement `afterCompletion(int status)` to log the status or store it in a `ThreadLocal` variable for later usage.

```
public class LogTransactionSynchronization extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {
   @Override
   public afterCompletion(int status) {
      // log the status or store it for later usage
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following to your log4j.properties will enable transaction status logging,

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=DEBUG,R
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG,R
```