# Display jdbc transaction events with log4j

Tags: spring, transactions, log4j

I'd like to see the transaction activity in Spring, such as:

```
TransactionInterceptor] - Getting transaction for x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo
  <!-- the transactional advice kicks in here... -->
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo]
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Acquired Connection
    [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@a53de4] for JDBC transaction

  <!-- the insertFoo(..) method from DefaultFooService throws an exception... -->
[RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should
    rollback on java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[TransactionInterceptor] - Invoking rollback for transaction on x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo
    due to throwable [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException]
```

and the log4j.properties I have configured are as follows:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework.transactions=DEBUG
```

However it doesn't produce the above output. Which property am I missing in order to display the transaction activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
 log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager=DEBUG
```

reference
[Transaction log4j](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?20483-Transaction-rollback-problem/page2)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

as specified [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965454/showing-a-spring-transaction-in-log).

Pay attention at the name of the logger that is same as yours without the last character.

Comment: thanks.i try log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG,but it also don't display what i what.