# two methods in one transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactional

I have a DAO class with two following methods:

```
@Transactional
public void save() throws Exception {

}

@Transactional
public void save2() {

}
```

In the service class I call those methods as follows:

```
public void processDAO() {
    dao.save();
    dao.save2();
}
```

My question is, will those methods run as part of the same transaction or in independent transactions or none of these?

Thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 4):

If the processDAO() method or the class of this method or a method/class which is higher in the call stack is also annotated with `@Transactional`, then they will run in the same transaction, otherwise in two different transactions.

Answer (score 4):

they will run in  independent transactions.
you can refrence to [Showing a Spring transaction in log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965454/showing-a-spring-transaction-in-log) to check it.
if you want processDAO methond in the same transaction
you can add @Transactional on processDAO method