# @EnableTransactionManagement in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, transactions

Is `@EnableTransactionManagement` required in Spring Boot?
I did some research. Some folks say you don't need it, as Spring Boot has it already enabled, others say you do have to use it explicitly. So how is it?

Answer (score 98):

Probably you're also using Spring Data. Calls on Spring Data repositories are by default surrounded by a transaction, even without `@EnableTransactionManagement`. If Spring Data finds an existing transaction, the existing transaction will be re-used, otherwise a new transaction is created.

`@Transactional` annotations within your own code, however, are only evaluated when you have `@EnableTransactionManagement` activated (or configured transaction handling some other way).

You can easily trace transaction behavior by adding the following property to your `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
```

(see [Showing a Spring transaction in log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965454/showing-a-spring-transaction-in-log))

Answer (score 45):

According to  > https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

**Spring Boot will** detect spring-jdbc on the classpath and h2 and will **create a DataSource and a JdbcTemplate for you automatically**. Because such infrastructure is now available and you have no dedicated configuration, a **DataSourceTransactionManager will also be created for you**: this is the component that intercepts the @Transactional annotated method.

You can also use **spring-boot-starter-actuator** to list your beans created in your context and you will find it

bean": "transactionManager"

Comment: So the answer is: If you have spring-jdbc on your classpath, you don't need @EnableTransactionManagement, right?

Comment: only if you have @EnableAutoConfiguration in your configuration class though. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @kekko12 `@EnableAutoConfiguration is added by @SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 36):

Little old post but the answers given previously were not straight forward when I was searching for it.

`@EnableTransactionManagement` is **optional** in Spring boot, provided that **spring-data*** or **spring-tx** are found in classpath. How it works?  As below:

Spring boot adds a ***spring-boot-autoconfigure.jar*** in the classpath. Go to the META-INF's spring.factories file and you can see `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration` entry there.  This initializes the transaction auto configuration for you.

Note that the class has following lines: (snippet)

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({PlatformTransactionManager.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter({JtaAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({TransactionProperties.class})
public class TransactionAutoConfiguration {
..
}
```

Have a look at `TransactionAutoConfiguration` to see that it enables transaction support if the `PlatformTransactionManager` is available in classpath. `EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration` is also configured there.

Comment: `only if you have @EnableAutoConfiguration in your configuration class though` So it's not true?

Comment: @Alex78191 `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is added by `@SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 16):

**No**. `@EnableTransactionManagement` is on by default, see that: https://github.com/jkubrynski/spring-boot/commit/9d219ef7a004c58a88bbbef82a520a22961c9402

Answer (score 5):

@EnableTransactionManagement is conditionally turned on/off based of the dependency jars we add in the classpath. If we use spring data jpa starter it is turned on.

Answer (score 4):

In the class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration`, there is such code(Spring Boot 1.5+):

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = false)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.aop", name = "proxy-target-class", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = false)
    public static class JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration {

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.aop", name = "proxy-target-class", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public static class CglibAutoProxyConfiguration {

    }
```

The default is `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true`, enabling CGLIB proxy by default.
If you want to use JDK proxy, set `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false` instead.