# How do I see if transaction management is enabled in my spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions

I want to see if my application (written using spring boot) has transaction management enabled.

How can I do this both programmatically and by code inspection (annotations, etc) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the EnableTransactionManagement annotation within your application, by hand or programmatically (use AnnotationUtils).

Or turn on trace for transactions:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724100/enabletransactionmanagement-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the below snippet inside a transactional method.

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
```

Comment: If you provide a link to documentation showing that, I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: I am not sure why you need a link.. here u go https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html