# spring jpa @transaction doesn't rollback

Tags: java, jpa

My project encountered the problem that Spring JPA transactions would not roll back. The project framework is spring MVC + Spring + spring data JPA + oracle. I searched a lot of information on the Internet, but still could not solve my problem.

I've tried many ways, such as setting the method to public or adding `rollbackFor = Exception.class` in `@Transactional`, but it still can't be solved.

Here's my code

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"addUser"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean insertUser() throws Exception{
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(10);
        userServiceI.addUser(user);
        return true;
    }
```

Service

Service Interface

```
public interface UserServiceI {
    void addUser(User user);
}
```

Service Implementation class

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserServiceI {

    @Autowired
    public UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void addUser(User user){
        User user1 = userDao.saveAndFlush(user);
        System.out.println(1/0);
    }
}
```

Dao

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {
}
```

My `@Transactional` method loads my implementation class Service, which writes an error-prone 1/0. I expect the transaction to roll back after the error, but it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have the `@EnableTransactionManagement` in your configuration? If not the `@Transactional` doesn't do anything.

Comment: can you paste the code of userdao class saveandflush method

Comment: @M.Deinum : thats simply wrong, transactions are enabled by default if you're using spring data _(which is what almost all people do)_ : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724843/351861

Comment: No they aren't. They are only enabled for the individual repository methods. Not for other methods. Hence the `@Transactional` even when using Spring Data is useless.

Comment: you clearly didnt understand what i wrote. Maybe reading it again might help. Hint : the key information is hidden between the words "if" and "which". Your "other methods" are not spring data. Rolling up your own persistence layer is not spring data. Business methods usually are not spring data.

Comment: @M.Deinum：my project it's a non springboot project. and xml configuration file (where is declared your component-scan) the annotation-driven tag.If I hadn't written it, I would have missed NullPointerException when I used this service.

Comment: @vinay chhabra：the saveandflush method is method of springdatajpa。if you use the springdatajpa you will Understand。

Comment: @钟光喜 : Is `UserDao` annotated with `@Repository`?

Comment: If you use xml you need `<tx:annotation-driven />` else it won't work. If you are using XML then make sure you aren't scanning for the same components twice (both in the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`. If you'r transactions don't work (and they don't) then your tx setup is wrong/missing/borked. Regardless of the fact that Spring Data JPA is transactional by default, as that only applies to the `saveAndFlush` method, after that the tx has committed and nothing can be rolled back.

Comment: Oh, I solved it because I omitted <context: component-scan base-package="com.bxoon"/> in applicationContext.xml. I only wrote <context: component-scan base-package="com.bxoon"/> in spring-mvc.xml. I always thought that I only need to write this in one of them.

Until I saw this article https://labreeze.iteye.com/blog/2359957. I am too happy and negligent. Thank you @ M. Deinum for saying whether to scan repeatedly, which inspired me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you are in a springboot project context you have to add @EnableTransactionManagement in your configuration class

if it's a non springboot project, add in your xml configuration file (where is declared your component-scan) the annotation-driven tag

Comment: wrong. Spring data has transaction management enabled by default : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724843/351861

Comment: my project it's a non springboot project. and xml configuration file (where is declared your component-scan) the annotation-driven tag.If I hadn't written it, I would have missed NullPointerException when I used this service

Comment: apparently, spring does not need the annotation to successfully create a valid repository out of the interface - i guess they changed this requirement some time ago : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/jpa21/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/storedprocedures/UserRepository.java

Comment: Oh, I solved it because I omitted <context: component-scan base-package="com.bxoon"/> in applicationContext.xml. I only wrote <context: component-scan base-package="com.bxoon"/> in spring-mvc.xml. I always thought that I only need to write this in one of them.

Until I saw this article https://labreeze.iteye.com/blog/2359957. I am too happy and negligent. Thank you @ M. Deinum for saying whether to scan repeatedly, which inspired me.

Comment: The answer is correct, but I didn't understand him at first.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `@Repository` in your **UserDao** can be a possible fix of that error.
Not sure but it can work.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. and i think the UserDao extends for JpaRepository so Unwanted @Repository

Comment: `UserDao extends for JpaRepository so Unwanted @Repository `--- what?

Comment: @specializt -_-。i'm sorry。I'm from China. My English is poor

Comment: @specializt I mean this Dao doesn't need to write @Repository。

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solved it because I omitted  in applicationContext.xml. I only wrote  in spring-mvc.xml. I always thought that I only need to write this in one of them. Until I saw this article labreeze.iteye.com/blog/2359957. I am too happy and negligent.