# Understaning of @Transactional in Spring Boot - though exception changes doesn't rollback in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to understand @Transactional in spring - to test it I create simple project:

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    String name;
    Integer age;

    public Model(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface ModelRepository extends CrudRepository<Model,Long> {
    }
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Autowired
    private ModelRepository modelRepository;

    @Transactional
    public String doSomething(Integer number) {
        Model test = modelRepository.save(new Model("test", number));
        if(number>4) throw new RuntimeException();

        return test.name;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/search/{number}")
    public String search(@PathVariable Integer number){

        return exampleService.doSomething(number);
    }
}
```

When I go to *localhost:8080/search/1* - all goes well and object is saved in database.

But when I go *localhost:8080/search/10* - as I wanted - it throws Exception, but still object is saved in database.

Shouldn't be rollback here? Method which is annotated with @Transactional is public and in other bean.

Edit:
application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testtt?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '12'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TransactionalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransactionalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)` and put this annotation in your repository.

Comment: What database are you using? And how is the connection configured?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I updated question and it is MySQL 5.7

Comment: This should work. Which Transactional annotation do you have in your import?

Comment: @Zorglube is that property exists? couse I have only rollbackOn

Comment: @SimonMartinelli import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Comment: Looks like transaction management is not enabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724100/enabletransactionmanagement-in-spring-boot

Comment: You can try adding Transactional annotation on repository save()

Comment: Can you show your Spring Application Class?

Comment: I updated answer :)

Comment: debug it.find  out the code if it go though Transation AOP.

Comment: Previous commentators are absolutely right. An example based on database H2 works exactly, similar on the mySQL8. The error is not in the above code.

Must be searched in the rest of the ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Sample of config with spring, jpa, hibernate and c3p0.

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.company")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class PersistenceConfig {

        @Value("${hibernate.showSql}")
        private boolean showSql;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties("c3p0.named-configs.pool")
        @Qualifier("myDataSource")
        public DataSource myDataSource() {
            return new ComboPooledDataSource();
        }

        @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager esTransactionManager(@Qualifier("em") EntityManagerFactory em) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(em);
        return transactionManager;
    }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em(@Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource myDataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(myDataSource);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceUnit");
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.company");
            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(@Value("${hibernate.dialect}") String hibernateDialect,
                                                 @Value("${hibernate.showSql}") boolean showSql) {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(hibernateDialect);
            jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(showSql);
            return jpaVendorAdapter;
        }
    }
```