# Is @EnableTransactionManagement enabled by default?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

In my application I have **no** `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation (checked x times).

However, I still get a `jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException` if I do not annotate a service method as `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

Is `@EnableTransactionManagement` enabled by default?
What I'm missing here?

```
@Repository
public class PersistencePostgresImpl implements Persistence {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        DbUserEntity entity = em.find(DbUserEntity.class, user.getUserUID());
        if(entity == null){
            throw new UserNotFoundException(user.getUserUID());
        }

        entity.setLoginName(user.getAccessData().getUserName());
        entity.setUserData(user);
    }
}

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Inject
    private Persistence persistence;

    @Transactional
    public void updateUserData(User user) {
       persistence.saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

My configuration is (empty):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:persistence.properties")
public class PersistenceConfiguration {
}
```

persistence.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=... 
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
```

Springboot: 3.2.1
Hibernate: 6.4.1

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the complete `PersistenceConfiguration` and also your pom.xml if you use maven or whatever depenedencies which are used in the project

Comment: My PersistenceConfiguration is empty, only for datasource properties. I will update pom dependencies now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on your main class, you'll also have `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

That's why `TransactionAutoConfiguration` from `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction` jumps in (most probably you have spring-jdbc on classpath).

See [@EnableTransactionManagement in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724100/enabletransactionmanagement-in-spring-boot) for reference.