# Transactional not working with JPA saveAll

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to save a list of entity objects. Here is my method which is defined in a Service class:

```
@Transactional
public void creteEmployee(List<Employee> employeeList) {
    employeeRepository.saveAll(employeeList);
}
```

And here is my JPA repository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {
    Page<Employee> findByCompany(Pageable pageable, Company company);
}
```

I've a unique constraint defined in my entity. If any item from the `employeeList` violates the unique constraint, I expect no one from the `employeeList` will be saved. Unfortunately all items except the problematic one is saved and also an `DataIntegrityViolationException` is raised. What should be done to make it atomic?

Comment: How do you determine they are all saved? Can you log the transactions and check if they happen at the expected points in time? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965454/showing-a-spring-transaction-in-log

Comment: If I check in DB, I can see rows are stored.

Comment: Sounds like your transactions infrastructure isn't setup properly.