# How do I configure DataSource and transaction manager programmatically

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Im' trying to understad how to configure persistence in Spring 6 (without boot). So far I'm using this configuration file for hibernate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.community.dialect.H2LegacyDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./spring</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.cypherf.model.Message"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my code looks like this:

```
@Repository
public class MessageRepository implements CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public @NonNull <S extends Message> S save(@NonNull S message) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return message;
    }
}
```

I't working, but I'd like to learn how to use the @Transactional annotation. From what I gathered,
I need to use @EnableTransactionManagement on my @Configuration class. But that's not enough as if I add @EnableTransactionManagement and @Transactional to my repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MessageRepository implements CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public @NonNull <S extends Message> S save(@NonNull S message) {
        //em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(message);
        //em.getTransaction().commit();
        return message;
    }
}
```

entities stop being persisted. What (I think) I understood is that I haven't declared a TransactionManager? But that's where I'm stuck as I don't understand how/where to do that. And most of the examples I find use Spring Boot and I don't.

Comment: First of all, you're not supposed to **implement** a `CrudRepository` yourself, the idea is that Spring Data will generate one for you as soon as you **extend** from it. Secondly, a quick look at the [Javadoc for @EnableTransactionManagement](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) will tell you all you need to know in order to get started

Comment: If I simply extend CrudRepository I get the following error: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<com.cypherf.model.Message, java.lang.Long>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: I looked at a lot of documentation for the past week but it's really hard to grasp everything I feel really lost. For example in this doc they use datasource(), but I haven't understood yet how to configure my datasource.

Comment: Make it interface `public interface MessageRepository implements CrudRepository<Message, Long> {}` and Spring will automatically generate bean of its implementation with all default methods

Comment: @Nikolai Shevchenko If I simply extend CrudRepository I get the following error: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<com.cypherf.model.Message, java.lang.Long>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: think that i know what happen . would you consider to offer a  bounty for this question too ? happy to look into it if it has

Comment: @crizzis thank you for your first comment it helped me understand how to use CrudRepository. About the second point, I made progress but still fail to understand something, I explain it here if you want to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77168078/jpa-transaction-even-without-transactional-enabletransactionmanagement