# JPA transaction even without @Transactional/@EnableTransactionManagement

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm trying to understand how transactions work with Spring. I have a repository interface extending CrudRepository:

```
@Transactional
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
}
```

And a PersistenceConfig that I use to create my EntityManagerFactory and TransactionManager:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceConfig.class);

    public static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf == null) {
            synchronized (EntityManagerFactory.class) {
                if (emf == null) {
                    final StandardServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .configure() // Configures setting from hibernate.cfg.xml
                            .build();
                    try {
                        emf = new MetadataSources(sr).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(sr);
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return emf;
    }
}
```

Thing is, I use a logger to debug JpaTransactionManager, and no matter if I use the annotations @Transactional/@EnableTransactionManager, I can see transactions are used:

```
3576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
3576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(2090037997<open>)] for JPA transaction
[...]
3576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction commit
3576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(2090037997<open>)]
[...]
3576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(2090037997<open>)] after transaction
```

So, what's the point of using these?

Comment: If you will remove `@Transactional` from repository interface. The invoke will not be in transaction

Comment: @AndreiLisa but the logs are provided are from a run where I removed @Transactional/@EnableTransactionManager. You can clearly see a TransactionManager using a transaction.

Comment: also Which method from repository are you using ?

Comment: Every method! Including save and delete.

Comment: If you will open Java docs of the method you will see that there are present transactional annotation on methods level

Comment: What methods? The ones from CrudRepository? I dont see any annotation when I open that class.

Comment: I will write an answer about this topic to this question

Comment: Can you check the answer and reference from there ? Also if it help you don’t forget to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why transactional are invoked when the method is not explicitly declared with `@Transactional` annotation is it:

According to documentation and Java docs

> By default, methods inherited from CrudRepository inherit the
> transactional configuration from SimpleJpaRepository. For read
> operations, the transaction configuration readOnly flag is set to
> true. All others are configured with a plain @Transactional so that
> default transaction configuration applies. Repository methods that are
> backed by transactional repository fragments inherit the transactional
> attributes from the actual fragment method.

To have more details about it I suggest you to read documentation, mainly [5.1.7. Transactionality](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions)

Comment: I see! Amazing thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Spring-data-jpa by default will configure `@Transactional` behind the scene on every non query methods on the `CrudRepository`. That means even you do not configure `@Transactional` / `@EnableTransactionManagement` , the `@Transactional` stuff are still there and hence you will see them in the logs.

You can turn off such default behaviour by:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(enableDefaultTransactions=false)
```

where `enableDefaultTransactions` has the following [meaning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#enableDefaultTransactions()) :

> Configures whether to enable default transactions for Spring Data JPA
> repositories. Defaults to true. If disabled, repositories must be used
> behind a facade that's configuring transactions (e.g. using Spring's
> annotation driven transaction facilities) or repository methods have
> to be used to demarcate transactions.

The point of defining `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@Transactional` by yourself is that it gives you more flexibility to define transaction boundary that you want. You can extend it across your business service methods or even broader but not just limit to the methods on the repository level.